# My Laptop sound suddenly went off

Tags: windows-7, audio, virus

My Laptop's sound suddenly died on me.

I had some issues with Viruses & anti-viruses recently :/

I'd uninstalled my previous anti-virus AVG... but apparently it hadn't completely uninstalled.. and i wasn't aware of it.
My Laptop had suddenly gone super slow, i figured it had to be because of some kinda virus as it kept repeating explorer processes repeatedly... and downloaded Kaspersky... but after installing kaspersky, the two antiviruses installed got some kinda conflict?? my laptop basically crashed. I ran the chkdsk command... got my pc repaied... but now my sound isn't working :/

I tried restarting the system quite a few times...
used a headset and it doesn't show any sound yet...
it doesn't even show the 'bing' hardware sound...

any help plz?

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any specific reason a virus would stop sound.

Starting with the basics. Make sure your speakers aren't turned off from the tray icon in the bottom right. Also go into your Control Panel > Sound:

You can run tests against your current sound configuration and ensure your system is reading sound from the correct location etc:

There is a simple troubleshooting guide provided by  [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/tips-fixing-common-sound-problems#tips-fixing-common-sound-problems=windows-7) if you want another good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsview.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)! And download the drivers which suits your PC requirement. Re install the driver. Do let me know if you are still having the same problem.

Comment: Please give your laptop details to get good solution!